# Bypass XSS filter

Tags: xss

So i found a website that encloses every thing i searched in double quotes("searched term" ) and places it in a value parameter i tried following vectors hoping that first i would close the double quotes then close the input tag

```
"/><img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>
"/><script>alert(1)</script>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.The script is injected in the page but is not being executed

```
value=""/><img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>"
```

above is value of attribute after i inject the vector.I have attached an image for further reference .

Can any one suggest something .What am i missing[image]

**update**

[image]

Comment: This happens because the developer tools of your browser misrepresent the value of the property. Likely the attribute is correctly escaped, but your browser is trying to be helpful by showing in unescaped. Note how the tag in your example is completely blue and not syntax highlighted like the rest of the tag.

Comment: @Sjoerd is exactly right. The inspector in Chrome doesn't reflect the exact source code and resolves HTML-encoded characters in HTML attributes to their representation. So it only *looks* like the `"` is unescaped. To see the real source code try CTRL+U or use an interception proxy.

Comment: you guys are absolutly right...
if i click on the TAG and click edit HTML,then you can see double quotes are being encoded....

<input id="search" type="search" name="q" value="&quot;/><img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">

Comment: So, is there a way to by pass it....
i will try encoding and double encoding

Comment: @shujaat: no, I can tell you there's no way that will ever work based on the devtools shot. Basically, it's setting the attribute (more likely a _.value_, but let's not get distracted) with the DOM API, not injecting it into the page's hard-coded source. you can cram any aribtrary code into an attribute with the DOM and it's all a benign string value. only when it comes in bad embeded raw in the page can such XSS work. if the page doesn't refresh when you search, you know it's a dom-based update, and you can give up.

Comment: Hmmmm,
my input also gets reflected on the page as text saying search result for 'searched value' .Its looks embedded on the page and the attack vector is enclosed by single quotes .So i tried '<img src=x onerror=prompt(1)>
but <> are being encoded.(i have attached a picture in the main question)

Comment: single qoute is not being encoded but <> are .